# Can radio waves be made to travel as or along a particle beam?

Tags: antenna, antenna-theory, frequency, transmitter, physics

Can a laser  be used as an antenna?

Can a beam of any type extend transmission distance of an electromagnetic field?

https://medium.com/starts-with-a-bang/this-is-why-the-2018-nobel-prize-in-physics-for-lasers-is-so-important-21bef2dab7d8

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "Electricity can travel along a laser *below*"?

Comment: I used to be very good friends with the late Bob Manor, a scientist who worked for a company called Energistics in Ohio, back in the late '70s or early '80s. They developed a technology for superimposing a 13 MHz radio signal on a laser beam. (The company broke up due to infighting between the two owners.) Is this what you are talking about?

Comment: None of your three questions make any physical sense. I'm afraid there's nothing to answer but "No, and asking that makes no sense". Please ask something based on your current understanding of physics, not based on sci-fi fantasies!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I don't blame you for saying what you did. Part of what the OP says is, well ... see my comment. In addition to my scientist friend, I knew a sharp fellow who attended an Energistics presentation. I was convinced and intrigued. Let's see what the OP has to say.

Comment: The company presently named Energistics is a completely different firm.

Comment: @MikeWaters I won't be putting Muze down here, but his/her grab on physics is so slim that the electronics stackexchange site had to suspend Muze's account because he was flooding the site with questions of exactly this type: vague questions that strongly indicate OP hasn't understand the basics about what they make hypothetical speculations about. I'd very much like to be proven wrong, however! In any case, these are **three** separate questions, and OP should focus on one, imho, and explain where it's coming from!

Comment: This question is probably better suited for physicsSE, **IF** it is clarified.

Comment: @MikeWaters hold on there.  I have a real interest and what doesn't make sense?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Oh really? Okay. :-) In any case, this got my attention because I've never heard anything about that original invention since. Thanks.

Comment: @MikeWaters the physicsSE folks blocked Muze, for a year. Guess why...

Comment: @muze "what doesn't make sense?": all three of your questions. 1.: what does it mean for a laser to transmit like an antenna? A laser is an emitter of electromagnetic waves, but fundamentally different than an antenna. 2. There's no transmission distance for electromagnetic waves. They travel to infinity unless they hit an obstacle. How would a laser increase "infinity"? 3. "Electricity can travel along a laser" simply: no, that's wrong.

Comment: @MarcusMüller for editing to much.

Comment: @MarcusMüller does this help?

Comment: you improved nothing and made the last question worse. If you care about wave physics, you'll have to go through the route of learning the basics of these. That's math, and not asking what you call in your profile "abstract questions"; your questions simply are detached from anything that resembles physics and make no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Light waves and RF waves are both electromagnetic radiation. The only difference is that we can see the narrow band of frequencies that we call light.

There is a common misconception that laser irradiance does not follow the inverse square law that describes the irradiance of an antenna. But in fact, they are exactly the same. The only difference is that the laser has a huge boost in initial intensity compared to an antenna. But thereafter, the laser irradiance decays following the same inverse square law.

The stark difference in initial intensity and the much higher frequency of the laser compared to typical RF systems makes it an attractive candidate to use for long distance, high speed communications. These facts have not escaped NASA's and the JPL's attention.   An experimental system, dubbed [OPALS](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/861.html) (optical payload for lasercom science) has been used to transmit images from a ground station to the ISS.

OPALS used a simple 50 megabit OOK (on off keying) modulation with a forward error correction code to transmit video files. The signal is therefore a 50 MHz modulation of a 1,550 nanometer carrier. No different than an RF transmitter other than the use of much higher frequencies.